# Using logAnalyzer with log4j syslog appender

Tags: log4j, syslog, rsyslog

I am trying to send syslog messages from my web application to RSYSLOG and then view them in logAnalyzer.
I manage to see the logs but the following fields are not shown in the main table: Facility, Sevirty, ProcessID. They do appear in the messages, but their columns are empty.

In what format should I send them message so that the logAnalyser will be able to parse it correctly? 
I am looking for the right log4j.appender.SYSLOG_LOCAL1.layout.conversionPattern string to place in my log4j.xml file.

Comment: What's your current log4j configuration?

Answer (score 0):

Here is my log4j.properties file. 
I  am using LOCAL1 as the SYSLOG facility:

```
log4j.rootLogger=DEBUG, R, stdout ,SYSLOG_LOCAL1

log4j.appender.R=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.R.File=${CATALINA_HOME}logs/mylweb.log
log4j.appender.R.MaxFileSize=10MB
log4j.appender.R.MaxBackupIndex=100
log4j.appender.R.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.R.layout.ConversionPattern=%p %t %c - %m%n

log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%d %p [%c] - <%m>%n

log4j.category.org.springframework=INFO
log4j.category.org.directwebremoting=INFO
log4j.category.org.apache.http=INFO

log4j.appender.SYSLOG_LOCAL1=org.apache.log4j.net.SyslogAppender
log4j.appender.SYSLOG_LOCAL1.threshold=DEBUG
log4j.appender.SYSLOG_LOCAL1.syslogHost=localhost
log4j.appender.SYSLOG_LOCAL1.facility=Local1
log4j.appender.SYSLOG_LOCAL1.facilityPrinting=true
log4j.appender.SYSLOG_LOCAL1.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.SYSLOG_LOCAL1.layout.conversionPattern=%d %p [%c] - %m%n
```